# What happens if EF6 transaction is interrupted?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, transactions

I'm using *EF6 transactions* `context.database.BeginTransaction()` with SQL Server.

If I `Commit()` or `Rollback()` transaction I see TM:Commit and TM:Rollback Transaction message in SQL Server profiler and the table is unlocked.

But if I kill **IIS process** (with my application) after transaction has been opened, locked tables become unlocked (I guess connection with the EF is interrupted and the transactions are closed automatically) and no rollback messages is displayed in SQL profiler.

Why? Is it correct? Will SQL server close transaction anyway?

Comment: Actually, the question isn't related to C# programming at all, and asks about behavior of SQL Server. Thus, I've voted for off-topic. Anyway, here's the answer: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47404/does-disconnecting-the-network-stop-a-query

Comment: I couldn't select SQL Server tags because stack overflow requires more than 1500 score. Thanks for answer